# Difference between rahat and maha rahat

Tags: theravada

This is more directed to someone who understands Sinhalese.

Is there difference between Rahath and Maha rahath? Is it interchangeable?

In the texts some places it says rahath and in some places it refers as maha rahath.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question does not appear to be about Buddhist philosophy, teaching, and practice, within the scope defined in the help center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rahat=Arhat

"Arhat" (or "Arahant" in Pali) refers to an enlightened being who has attained liberation from the cycle of birth and death (samsara). The term "Maha Arhat" or "Maha Arahant" is not a distinct category; rather, it is a way of emphasizing the greatness or excellence of an Arhat.

Both "Arhat" and "Maha Arhat" essentially refer to the same state of enlightenment, with the latter being a form of honorific or qualifier to highlight the advanced spiritual attainment of a particular individual.

So, in essence, they are not two different types of beings but rather terms used to emphasize the degree of spiritual accomplishment. The prefix "Maha" means "great" or "supreme," indicating an especially elevated level of realization.